# How to define a configurable type guard factory in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to be able to "configure" a factory to create type guarding functions. Such that I can pass in the functions (keyed by name) and then create type guarders for them. ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAzigPAFQHxQLxQDawATnBADRSYC6AUKJFAGICGAlgDZwnQGEAzVpxSUorAHYh6jaACVUcTsCy4C8JKgw4oAHxYduvBuGgA1YewAmrYAHsSq-FAAUADwBc4qQEp8uBRQlFRwTJgtOa1sHFGcAbzooIgBrCBAvFFJ2CQBzGi9Vdy9JED88AMVlVToAXzow82FyJwJMKAg3YAgJK1iIqPtHbIEIEigzXAB+cagvCQgAN1H6hDsJTKhViQF2HJ4+KHQzds7u3vHLG0GUbBcFy+iSFC8zMtwEpN5gHglDgGkTl0erFUiA7AJxrdQV4-m8oB8klAvj9Dm0OkDzhFmmZCH8aNhbp5vKUvG4oOxYm1yvDEoiklsNvdIlcHM4mQMYoRQfQ6fS1htCOyrDQ2Q9Bu4fLS6ciSL8hVKoHUknU6nQGcAoEIEIMQM4tjs9rwXAiJHAALYAI1GXiKxLhsnBUDJeBdUAA5KbLaM3VBpsQyGI3CKvIJhKIqG6AJISIUAQjd9BqkrV-I1FIAcuarWMCFqdS4PVnvcn1VAmc4ACwAJnEsTgEmSEjsAHcJPV2BCXBmiyQ7sIfH4EUzakA))

```
type Success<T> = [true, T]
type Failure = [false, any]
type Result<T> = Success<T> | Failure
type Validator<T> = (x: any) => Result<T>
type Validators = {
  [key: string]: <T>(x: any) => Result<T>
}

type Value<T> = T extends Validator<infer V> ? V : never

const configure = <V extends Validators>(validators: V) => {
  return <K extends keyof V>(key: K) => {
    return <T extends Value<V[K]>>(x: any): x is T => {
      const validator = validators[key]
      const [valid] = validator(x)
      return valid
    }
  }
}
```

Which then could be used as...

```
const factory = configure({
  number: (x: any) => typeof x === 'number' ? [true, x] : [false, 'Invalid!']
  // ^ Error here!
})

const isNumber = factory('number')

const val = 42 as unknown

if (isNumber(val)) {
  val
}
```

But that results in this compilation error:

```
(property) number: (x: any) => [true, number] | [false, string]
Type '(x: any) => [true, number] | [false, string]' is not assignable to type '<T>(x: any) => Result<T>'.
  Type '[true, number] | [false, string]' is not assignable to type 'Result<T>'.
    Type '[true, number]' is not assignable to type 'Result<T>'.
      Type '[true, number]' is not assignable to type 'Success<T>'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.(2322)
input.ts(6, 3): The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

Why isn't it able to recognize the value for the type guard dynamically?

[TypeScript Playground link here!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAzigPAFQHxQLxQDawATnBADRSYC6AUKJFAGICGAlgDZwnQGEAzVpxSUorAHYh6jaACVUcTsCy4C8JKgw4oAHxYduvBuGgA1YewAmrYAHsSq-FAAUADwBc4qQEp8uBRQlFRwTJgtOa1sHFGcAbzooIgBrCBAvFFJ2CQBzGi9Vdy9JED88AMVlVToAXzow82FyJwJMKAg3YAgJK1iIqPtHbIEIEigzXAB+cagvCQgAN1H6hDsJTKhViQF2HJ4+KHQzds7u3vHLG0GUbBcFy+iSFC8zMtwEpN5gHglDgGkTl0erFUiA7AJxrdQV4-m8oB8klAvj9Dm0OkDzhFmmZCH8aNhbp5vKUvG4oOxYm1yvDEoiklsNvdIlcHM4mQMYoRQfQ6fS1htCOyrDQ2Q9Bu4fLS6ciSL8hVKoHUknU6nQGcAoEIEIMQM4tjs9rwXAiJHAALYAI1GXiKxLhsnBUDJeBdUAA5KbLaM3VBpsQyGI3CKvIJhKIqG6AJISIUAQjd9BqkrV-I1FIAcuarWMCFqdS4PVnvcn1VAmc4ACwAJnEsTgEmSEjsAHcJPV2BCXBmiyQ7sIfH4EUzakA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few function types that are unimplementably generic.  Here's the main problem:

```
type Validators = {
  [key: string]: <T>(x: any) => Result<T>
}
```

That's an object for which each property value is of type `<T>(x: any)=>Result<T>`, a generic function that claims to be able to produce a `Result<T>` *for any `T` the caller specifies*.  Such a function is hard to imagine: if you had one named `f`, and an unknown value named `x`, you could call it as`f<string>(x)` to see if `x` were a `string`, and then call it as `f<number>(x)` to see if `x` was a `number`, which would be amazing since `f` has only one runtime implementation.

So the compiler is correct to complain that your `Validator<number>` is not a `<T>(x: any)=>Result<T>`.   Really, nothing could be.

But that's not what you want the properties of `Validators` to be anyway. Really you want to say that each property is *some specific* `Validator<T>` but you don't know which one yet.  Conceptually this is called an [existential type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) but TypeScript doesn't easily support those.  You could possibly try to represent this as a mapped object type, but for now we will throw up our hands and change `<T>(x: any)=>Result<T>` to `Validator<any>`.  That's at least going to be possible to implement.

So now we have

```
const configure = <V extends {[k: string]: Validator<any>>(validators: V) => {...}
```

which is fine.  I usually prefer to replace the index signature with a self-referential mapped type like this:

```
const configure = <V extends Record<keyof V, Validator<any>>>(validators: V) => {...}
```

because it won't require that `validators` have an index signature, which will be fine if it is an object literal or of a type alias type, but will [fail if it of an interface type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).

---

Moving on: in your implementation, you have the type

```
<T extends Value<V[K]>>(x: any): x is T
```

which is again generic in a way that can't be implemented.  If `Value<V[K]>` is `number`, then this function would be `<T extends number>(x: any): x is T`.  With a function named `g` of this type and a value named `x`, you could call `g<123>(x)` to find out if `x` is `123`, and you could also call `g<456>(x)` to find out if `x` is `456`.  Unimplementable.  Let's change it to

```
(x: any): x is Value<V[K]>
```

which is what you really want: if `Value<V[K]>` is `number`, you get `(x: any): x is number`, a non-generic type guard function that you can actually implement.

---

So we put that all together and try it.  The compiler error goes away, and:

```
const factory = configure({
  number: (x: any) => typeof x === 'number' ? [true, x] : [false, 'Invalid!'], // okay
})

const isNumber = factory('number');
//const isNumber: (x: any) => x is string | number ?!
```

Oh dear.  For some reason, the compiler has inferred that `Value<(x: any) => [true, number] | [false, string]>` is `string | number`.  This inference isn't exactly *wrong*, but it's not as precise as it should be.  The solution here is to give up on the compiler's magical conditional inference `Validator<infer V>`, roll up our sleeves, and try to manually compute `V` from `T extends Validator<any>`:

```
type Value<T extends Validator<any>> = Extract<ReturnType<T>, [true, any]>[1]
```

That says: given a `T` that is a `Validator<any>`, first get its return type.  That's going to look like `[true, XXX] | [false, YYY]`.  From this, we should look only at the piece of that union matching `[true, any]`... so just `[true, XXX]`.  And finally, get the second element of that tuple type (using the `[1]` index) to get `XXX`.

Now, *finally*, this happens:

```
const factory = configure({
  number: (x: any) => typeof x === 'number' ? [true, x] : [false, 'Invalid!'],
})

const isNumber = factory('number');
//const isNumber: (x: any) => x is number

const val = 42 as unknown
if (isNumber(val)) {
  val.toFixed(1); // okay
}
```

Hooray!  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAzigPAFQHxQLxQDawATnBADRSYC6AUKJFAGICGAlgDZwnQGEAzVpxSUorAHYh6jaACVUcTsCy4C8JKgw4oAHxYduvBuGgA1YewAmrYAHsSq-FAAUADwBc4qQEp8uBRQlFR06EyYLbggsKAg3YAgJKxQoSOtbB3RJEGw1KABReJJWBBUFYB4JTFNVKmIyMWyabEIARno6BDsJFGAoLokBdgBzHj4odDNY+MTkqAUukit0AGsIEDsBVKo0m3tHbNzsFwA3Sz2HFC8zPzxcAG86KCheCpIJCYBpaYSklLWNlszMcAV5PrcHk9ni8IG8Pu4vNkfF43FB2ClIuRJoRPs1-FBHtDoQNelAzpx0vtnOTKZdCAD6ETniS+oQaVYaNTzhkSO4fFCia9KmTzgKoABfKGSyWdbqkoSlBwgZwDIajXguQlQCRwAC2ACMICQvAjvCAIVBZJsoKi8HaoAByHUGo0OqAAfiIpHIVDcnK8gmEoioDoAkhJ2QBCB00Ch0cX82U9ProgByesNJGcCv2IBcTozrp8AG46AB6MsstEodMu42uTxmi2o9HawskMJV8nOAAsACZxCk4BIVhI7AB3CR0dhbFxp9unYQ+Pxakl2TgQAB0nDsw0XnE39mY7DcECsLlay+LUArUH7m4ADPGgA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz! I definitely got very confused on over-using the generics there. Thank you for the detailed explanation of why each assumption wasn’t working. Really helps to understand it better!